# Discord.py bot messsage bypass

Tags: discord.py

I'm making a Discord bot that deletes blacklisted messages and then logs them into a channel. I've got the delete messages and log them sorted, but when it logs them, it just deletes it.

`if message.author.bot:`

thats what ive got for it  but i have no idea what scrit to use to make a bypass for the bot.

if anybody can help, that'd be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok nevermind im stupid

all I needed to do was this:

`if message.author.bot:`

`return`